# Java negative value hash codes

Tags: java, hashcode, polynomial-math, negative-number

so here is all of my code for reference.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Plagiarism {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //you are not using 'myPlag' anywhere, you can safely remove it
//      Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No files input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String foo = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[i]));
            foo = simplify(reader);
            // System.out.print(foo);
            int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int k = 0; k < foo.length() - blockSize + 1; k++) {
                list.add(foo.substring(k, k + blockSize));

                int x = 33;
                int hash = 0;
                for (String str: list) {
                    for (int o = 0; o < str.length(); o++) {
                        hash = 33*hash + str.charAt(o);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(hash);

                /* List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size());
                for (String myInt : list) {
                    newList.add(Integer.parseInt(myInt));

                    int x = 33;
                    int hash = 0;
                    for (int o = 0; o < newList.size(); o++) {
                        hash = x*hash + newList.get(o);
                    }
                } */


            }
            // System.out.print(list);
        }




    }

    public static String simplify(BufferedReader input)
            throws IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Although I want to in particular focus on this part:

```
int x = 33;
                    int hash = 0;
                    for (String str: list) {
                        for (int o = 0; o < str.length(); o++) {
                            hash = 33*hash + str.charAt(o);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(hash);
```

Some of the values returned are negative hash values. Why is this? Even when the block size is small (ie. 2) it is still doing it. I know it is something to do with "modulo p" perhaps? I am using Horner's polynomial method here.

I'm wondering if I could get some help on this?

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Why does it matter if hash codes are negative or not?

Answer (score 2):

Negative values are caused by integer overflow. Any integer number with the most significant bit set to `1` is *interpreted* as a negative number.

Hash codes do not signify anything in particular: all that is required of them is to be the same for equal values, and try to be as different as possible for non-equal values. That is why integer overflow can be safely ignored when dealing with hash codes.

Comment: it matters here because i have to stop the overload

Comment: @user3364788 Although you can always add `return Math.abs(hash)`, I would strongly recommend against relying on hash code being positive. Instead, I would either (1) add my own method - say, `positiveHash()`, or (2) used `Math.abs` in the method that uses `hashCode()` to avoid the dependency.

Comment: the problem is this: I now have to store these hash codes into a hash table. I have to make it so that numerical flow doesnt happen, using modulo "p". there can't be negative values. And even with this, it shouldn't have numerical overflow with small blocks?

Comment: @user3364788 Take a look at how `HashMap<K,V>` deals with this problem ([link to a source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java)). Look at the `put` method first, then at `hash(int)` and `indexFor(int,int)`. You can do the same thing to coerce the value, positive or negative, into a shorter range of values that are greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

A hash is an `int` type which can take negative values. A negative value should not concern you.

When a java `int` gets too big (just over 2 billion), it will wrap round to a negative value. That is what is happening here: your multiplication of 33 will eventually cause this wraparound to a negative.